# Add multiple Tasks to a User Story in DevOps using Client libraries

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying add multiple tasks to a new user story in Azure Dev Ops and am struggling to link the newly created tasks to the user story.

I can create the user story with no problems and thought I could use the same method to create the tasks and then link via the Parent field but this doesn't seem to work.

This is the code I use the create the tasks:

```
var useCase = _traceContext.UseCases.Include(u => u.DeconstructionStage).FirstOrDefault(u => u.ObjID == useCaseObjID);
        List<UseCaseADO> tasks;
        if (useCase.DeconstructionStage.StageOrder < 4)
        {
            tasks = new List<UseCaseADO> 
            {
                { new UseCaseADO { StackRank = "1", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Create Test Script", Description="See Create Test Script in the Working Practices document", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Discover(Test)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { StackRank = "2", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Create Discovery Trace", Description="See Create Discovery Trace in the Working Practices document", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Discover(Test)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { StackRank = "3", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Review Use Case (Dev)", Description="See Review Use Case (Dev) in the Working Practices document", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Discover(Dev)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { StackRank = "4", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Review Use Case (Test)", Description="See Review Use Case (Test) in the Working Practices document", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Discover(Test)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { StackRank = "5", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Create and Annotate Define Traces", Description="See Create and Annotate Define Traces in the Working Practices document", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Define(Dev)", Priority = "1" } }
            };

        }
        else
        {
            tasks = new List<UseCaseADO> 
            {
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "6", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Refactor Code", AssignedTo="", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", State="New", Tags="Deconstruct(Dev)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "7", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Deconstruction Test", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Deconstruct(Test)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "8", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Decommision Code", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Decommision(Dev)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "9", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Decommision Test", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Decommision(Test)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "10", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Decommision Data", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Decommision(Dev)", Priority = "1" } },
                { new UseCaseADO { ID = "", StackRank = "11", WorkItemType = "Task", Title1="Decommision Test", Description="", AcceptanceCriteria="", AssignedTo="", State="New", Tags="Decommision(Test)", Priority = "1" } }
            };

        }

        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
        VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(_uri), credentials);
        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

        try
        {
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = GetTaskPatchDoc(userStoryID, task);
                WorkItem result = workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, _project, "Task").Result;
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error creating user story: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
            return false;
        }
```

`GetTaskPatchDoc` looks like this

```
private JsonPatchDocument GetTaskPatchDoc(int userStoryID, UseCaseADO task)
    {
        JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "/fields/System.Title", task.Title1 },
            { "/fields/System.Description", task.Description},
            { "/fields/System.State", task.State },
            { "/fields/System.Tags", task.Tags },
            { "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank", task.StackRank},
            { "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority", task.Priority },
            { "/fields/System.Parent", userStoryID.ToString() }
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> value in values)
        {
            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = value.Key,
                    Value = value.Value
                }
           );
        }

        return patchDocument;
    }
```

The tasks are created correctly but I'm missing the link between the user story and the task.

Does anyone know how to do this via the client libraries ? I don't want to switch the code to the REST APIs as the rest of the code is working just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be easier than I imagined

For each task when building the PatchDoc for the user story

```
 patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/relations/-",
                    Value = new
                    {
                        rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
                        url = task.Url,
                        attributes = new { comment = "" }
                    }
                }
            );
```